# How to check if the record updated or inserted successfully Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I have Angular 7-8 project back end is Node.JS, I could not found a solution on how to check if my record inserted or updated successfully in database.

here is my service.ts file

```
  UpdateData(data, id) {
  try {
   return this.http.post(this.baseurl + "/update/" + id, data)
   .subscribe(result => console.log(result));

  } catch (err) {
    console.log("-------Error occurred update posting----" + err);
    this.handleError(err);
  }
 }
```

I want to check in my component.ts if the insert/update completed successfully or not after calling this service function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done within the subscribe method like below:

```
return this.http.post(this.baseurl + "/update/" + id, data)
.subscribe(result => console.log(result),
 (error) => {
    // error logic here
  },
 () => {
    // request success logic here
  });
```

However if you want to check for the error/success in your component you shouldn't subscribe in your service and perform the actual subscribe in your component like below:

service:

```
return this.http.post(this.baseurl + "/update/" + id, data);
```

In your component.ts

```
this.serviceInstance.UpdateData(data, id).subscribe(result => console.log(result),
(error) => { /* error logic */ }, () => { /* success logic */})
```

Comment: I added this part, but I need to check in my component.ts if the record inserted successfully so I popup the snackbar success or failed so that I popup the snackbar failed

Comment: the multiple parametered `subscribe` is deprecated the new syntax is `subscribe({ next: result => {}, error: err => {} })`

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L73-L79

Answer (score 1):

```
 this.http.post(this.baseurl + "/update/" + id, data).subscribe(result => {
      if (result.status == "SUCCESS") {
        console.log(result)
      } else {
        this.dataService.toster('Please try again later: somthing went wrong', "error")
      }
    }, err => {
      this.dataService.toster('Please try again later: somthing went wrong', "error")
    })
  }
```

Dataservice.ts

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
export class dataService {
 public tosterData = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
toster(data, status) {   
        const obj = {
            message: data,
            status: status
        }
        this.tosterData.next(obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class MyService {
  public UpdateData(data, id) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseurl + "/update/" + id, data);
  }
}
```

then

Subscribe error callback

```js
class MyComponent {
  public InsertRecord(data, id) {
    this.myService.UpdateData(data, id).subscribe({
       next: result => {
         // show success
       },
       error: err => {
         // show fail
       }
     });
  }
}
```

-- or --

async await to use try catch

```js
class MyComponent {
  public InsertRecord(data, id) {
    try {
      const result = await this.myService.UpdateData(data, id).toPromise();
      // show success
    } catch (err) {
      // show fail
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I check in my component.ts file that the record inserted successfully so I popup the snackbar success or if failed I popup the snackbar failed

Comment: ask a new question, but in short: `UpdateData(data, id) { return this.http.post(this.baseurl + "/update/" + id, data); }`